# Is Max String Length Metadata possible from WCF Data Services (OData)?

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am using WCF **Data** Services (OData) to expose some data that is a `varchar(10)` in my SQL Server Database.  (I am using entity framework to expose it.)

Is there a way to ask the OData endpoint how long a string can be (ie get the 10 from `varchar(10)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service is an EF based service, and your CSDL for the EF model contains the max string length attribute on the property, then the $metadata of the service will contain that attribute as well. The client can then parse the $metadata and ask for this.
Note that the WCF DS Client library doesn't have an API to do this though. You could use ODataLib and EdmLib to read the $metadata (or just plain XML). They are in Microsoft.Data.OData.dll and Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll in the latest CTP (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx).
Note though, that if the service is based on something else than EF, then it's currently not possible to customize the $metadata endpoint in WCF DS itself this way. You would have to expose the $metadata yourself in some other way.